# How to get a selection of SQLite columns to be accepted in Android contentprovider query?

Tags: android, sqlite

I've been going round and round on this.  If I set the column selection to null everything works fine.  When I try to make a selection of columns I get a fatal error "Unknown column in projection".  I have verified that the column names are correct.

Here is the column selection code:

```
String[] MyColumns = new String[] { MyTable.COLUMN_ID, MyTable.COLUMN_A, 
    MyTable.COLUMN_B, MyTable.COLUMN_C };
Uri Myuri = MyContentProvider.CONTENT_URI; //specify the content provider location (Uri)
Cursor Mycursor = getContentResolver().query(Myuri, MyColumns, null, null, null);
```

I've also tried putting the new String into the query instead of the MyColumns variable.  That fails too.  Help!  Any suggestions?

@Yul, @Praful Bhatnagar: Here is the table creation code as requested (note: this is contentprovider database):

```
public class MyTable {
// Define Database table and column names
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "MyTable";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_A = "test1";
public static final String COLUMN_B = "test2";
public static final String COLUMN_C = "test3";
```

// Database creation sql statement

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table " +TABLE_NAME+ "(" + 
    COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
    COLUMN_A + " text not null," +
    COLUMN_B + " long not null," +
    COLUMN_C + " real);";

public static void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
}
```

Comment: Please add code where you create database with those COLUMN_A... defined.

Comment: Please share the create table query for the table...

Comment: Here is the table creation code: